# jquery show/hide not working for dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a checkbox which will allow the users to show/hide certain features. So I have 2 divs with separate IDs and one div is added directly to my code and the second div is dynamically added through a plugin with the CSS `display:none`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#chkstatus").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#dv").show();
      $("#Add").hide(); //dynamic div
    } else {
      $("#dv").hide();
      $("#Add").show(); //dynamic div
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dv" class="forgo">
  <h1>Benefits</h1>
  <p></p>
</div>

<!-- The below code is not visible in the page source but visible in inspect element -->

<div id="Add" class="form-group" style="display:none">
  <input class="btn-block button" type="button" style="" value="Upload File">
</div>
```

The problem is that the show/hide is working perfectly to the `#dv` but nothing happens to `#Add`. It always stays hidden.

Can someone let me know how can make the show/hide work for the dynamically added div?

Comment: Please share the corresponding HTML.

Comment: `console.log($('[id="Add"]').length)` in your click handler and tell us what it logs.

Comment: Also as a small side note; `$(this).is(':checked')` should just be `this.checked`

Comment: Can you please add some HTML and CSS code? Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/g90sdp7c/

Comment: @TylerRoper I have added the HTML

Comment: @Taplar it logs `1`

Comment: check your Dom by inspection your created with same id?

Comment: check your Dom by inspection your created with same id?

Comment: @LiveEn Your code doesn't show any checkboxes... The example must reproduce the issue you're describing in order for us to come up with a solution. Please edit your question. Are you sure that the `#Add` doesn't have a parent that's hidden or something?

Comment: If the log is returning 1, then that means the element is being found.  If an issue is happening, you need to replicate it in your question, as currently that is not being done.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the event listener to the dynamically created `div` you should add an eventlistener on the parent (say `<div id='cont'></div>` ) which is ofcourse static in nature .

Say the event we are listening to is `click`, now whenever you click the parent you have the reference to the specific div (even if there a lot of dynamic divs like this) as a target attribute of the event. which you can find by digging the output in console log.

Why and How ??

This is because of event delegation and event bubbling i.e. the event bubbles up to the parent div and keep on bubbling up to the body in DOM tree.
So for this case, as the event is click( checkbox ) which is on some different element (no parent child relation with dynamically added div) so we can use `trigger` to fire our own custom event on the parent div.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#cont").on('myEvent1',function(){
            $(this).find('#dv').show();
            $(this).find('#Add').hide();  
        });
        $("#cont").on('myEvent2',function(){
            console.log($(this)); // This will o/p the #cont div containing both the static and dynamic div in it.   
            $(this).find('#dv').hide();
            $(this).find('#Add').show();  
        });
        $("#chk").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                console.log($(this)); // This will o/p the checkbox element 
                $("#cont").trigger('myEvent1');

            } 
            else {
                $("#cont").trigger('myEvent2');
            }
        });
    });
```

You can try to mold it for your exact purpose and can also use `toggle` to reduce the LOC.